# How to use textmode mask phone number in asp.net without using javascript

Tags: asp.net, maskedtextbox

ASP.NET provides a textmode property to mask textbox input. One of the masks is the phone mask, but this mask doesn't do anything, and the textbox doesn't show any mask for the input (for example the 'Date' mask does have a mask for input, and even a calender).

Is there any way to use the phone textmode to determine a mask for phone input without using JavaScript? I am interested in 2 alternative mask:

```
(123) 123-1234-123
(123) 12-1234-123
```

Comment: Your browser only execute javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the textmode property in `TextBox`. You can use the Regular Expression Validator as below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="phonebox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MyRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Invalid Number" ControlToValidate="phonebox"     ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{3}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```